# Angular Resource error in console

Tags: angularjs

I ve got an angular resource service which then returns the data to a controller and I get all the data plus the data by name.

My application works just fine in the browser but I get a resource error in the console. Bad resource configuration.

I had a look in various questions and everyone states that I need to set the configuration property isArray to either false or true.

I have tried to do this but I still get an error.

Any ideas much appreciated.

Here is my service :

```js
(function() {

  var app = angular.module('test');

  app.service('ContactResource', function($resource) {

      return $resource('/contacts/:firstname', {},
        {'update': {method: 'PUT'}},
        {'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: true }},
        {'get': { method: 'GET', isArray: false }}
      );
  });

}());
```

And here is my controller:

```js
(function() {

  var app = angular.module('test');

  app.controller('contactsCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams, ContactResource) {
    $scope.contacts = ContactResource.query();

    $scope.singlecontact = ContactResource.get({firstname: $routeParams.firstname});
  });

}());
```

The error I am getting is : Error: [$resource:badcfg] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.2/$resource/badcfg?p0=get&p1=object&p2=array&p3=GET&p4=%2Fcontacts

When I click it says :

Error in resource configuration for action `get`. Expected response to contain an object but got an array (Request: GET /contacts)

When I get the url is /contacts the response is :

[{EmailAddress:some@email.com, etc}]

When the url is /contacts/firstname the response is :

{EmailAddress:some@email.com,etc}

Comment: Here's a trick that should serve you for your whole career as a programmer: when you get an error, read it and try to make sense of it. If you don't understand it and ask a question, post it, because other people probably can understand it, or at least have already seen it happen. Ignoring the error is the best way to look for problems at the wrong places. Don't paraphrase the error, don't post two words of it, don't post just the message. Post the whole stack trace.

Comment: can you post the *full* error that you are receiving?

Comment: I have now updated the post with the error. Thanks for the advice guys

Comment: well, that error says the server returned an array, but you told angular you would be getting a single object.  What is returned if you just put the `http://example.com/contacts/somefirstname` in the address bar? a single item or an array?

Comment: It is a single object

Comment: Post the result in your question.

Comment: Just change it to `{'get': { method: 'GET', isArray: true }}` or check what your backend is sending

Comment: are you *sure* that `$routeParams.firstname` actually has a value?  the error seems to indicate that you didn't pass a parameter.

Comment: I have updated the question to show the responses I am getting from the server. Thank you guys.

Comment: No. The error complains about the *response* being an array instead of being an object.

Comment: It appears to me that `$routeParams.firstname === undefined`, so the resource is actually calling `/contacts/` instead of `/contacts/firstname`.  @Michelem, changing the get to `isArray: true` won't help, because unless the request is for the very first name in the array, the response would be an incorrect value.

Comment: So when I add /contacts the response is an array of objects and when I enter /contacts/firstname its responding with a single object.

Comment: yes, but `$resource` can only make the call with the data it has; a call to `/contacts/undefined` is really the same as a call to `/contacts/`.

Comment: @Claies if that's the case then how is this working? `$scope.singlecontact = ContactResource.get({firstname: $routeParams.firstname});`

Comment: @Claies by doing a `console.log($routeParams.firstname);` I get the name in the console so it doesn't really return undefined.

Comment: according to your error, the $resource is not calling `/contacts/firstname`, the error definitely says it's calling `/contacts`.

Comment: I will experiment a bit more and if I manage to get it to work I ll post my answer here. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding a new controller called single controller and by separating the service into two functions. Here is how my code looks like now.

This is the service:

```js
(function() {

  var app = angular.module('test');

  app.service('ContactResource', function($resource, $routeParams) {

    this.all = function() {
      return $resource('/contacts', {},
      {'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: true }}
    )};

    this.single = function() {
      return $resource('/contacts/:firstname', {firstname: '@firstname'},
        {'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: false }}
      );
    }
  });

}());
```

And the controllers :

```js
(function() {

  var app = angular.module('test');

  app.controller('contactsCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams, ContactResource) {

    $scope.contacts = ContactResource.all().query();

  });

  app.controller('singleCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams, ContactResource) {

    $scope.singlecontact = ContactResource.single().query({firstname: $routeParams.firstname});

  });

}());
```

For some reason which I am still not sure $resource wouldn't accept them into the same controller.